# 32-bit package from a repo that should only contain the 64 bit packages

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm

Trying to a do install of some packages and it seems that it is trying to pull a 32-bit package from a 64-bit repo.

```
Installing for dependencies:

cyrus-sasl-lib                     i686                  2.1.23-15.el6_6.1                   rhel-x86_64-server-6.6.z                 136 k
```

Currently it is a 64-bit package.

```
rpm -qa | grep cyrus-sasl-lib
cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.el6_3.1.x86_64
```

Any idea why it might be doing this why take the 32-bit one when the 64-bit is available to install.

```
yum search cyrus-sasl-lib

cyrus-sasl-lib.i686 : Shared libraries needed by applications which use     Cyrus SASL
cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64 : Shared libraries needed by applications which use Cyrus SASL
```

Comment: This is not a problem, see [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158244/what-is-the-difference-between-i686-and-x86-64-packages](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158244/what-is-the-difference-between-i686-and-x86-64-packages).

Comment: I did look at that post earlier in fact but , it does seem strange that a package that is already installed as a 64-bit version would then try and update to a 32-bit package ? In the link you provided earlier it states that it may want it for backward compatibility - but in my case both the i686 and the x86_64 are available so why not just go for x86_64 ?

Comment: The 64 bit package is not updated with 32 bit. You can install both - they will co-exists. For example installing skype on CentOS -64 bit you have to Install the necessary 32-bit packages.

Comment: This article is helpful: [https://www.redhat.com/magazine/009jul05/features/multilib/](https://www.redhat.com/magazine/009jul05/features/multilib/).