# "-sh: Cannot execute binary file" because of source compiled on "x86_64" and executed on "i686" platform

Tags: gcc, yocto

I need to run some USB NCM related test cases for which i have written some test code in .c file. I have compiled the .c file from Ubuntu Host by using GCC compiler and trying to run from Device's console but i'm getting "-sh: Cannot execute binary file" error. Device side we don't have GCC installed.

uname -a command gives following o/p in,

```
> Host:

    4.4.0-31-generic Ubuntu x86_64

> Device:

    3.14.55-yocto-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 12 13:34:50 CEST 2018 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I understand that there is environment difference from Host to Device. Anyways i need to compile and execute .c file in device side console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x86_64 and i686 instruction sets are not the same (for [more details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158244/what-is-the-difference-between-i686-and-x86-64-packages/472220#472220)).

Use this command to compile source on your host :

```
 gcc -m32 -mtune=i686 source.c -o source
```

if getting error like this `fatal error: *.h : No such file or directory` this means that you don't have proper a library for cross compilation

```
 sudo apt install g++-multilib
```

And run gcc command again

**Reference :**

[GCC man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)