# What is the deference between `arch` and `/etc/yum/vars/arch` at docker container?

Tags: centos, yum, docker, cpu-architecture

I use docker container on CentOS7 x86_64.

Docker container depends on the host system.

```
bash
$ arch
x86_64
```

The arch command shows the above host arch in the container.

I want to use the container as i686, so I write i686 in /etc/yum/vars/arch and /etc/yum/vars/basearch.

```
bash
$ cat /etc/yum/vars/arch
i686
$ yum install {package} # It will install i686 packages.
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between i686 and x86\_64 packages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158244/what-is-the-difference-between-i686-and-x86-64-packages)

Comment: It's not answer for me. I wonder that the between `arch` and `/etc/yum/vars/arch` i386 docker container on x86_64 host computer.